# Move span in new line if text is longer then block

Tags: css

I have block Component:

```html
<div class="block">
  <span class="wrapper">
    <span class="title">Title:</span>
    <span class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

And styles for it:

```css
.block {
  max-width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/*NEED TO ASSIGN THIS STYLES IF TEXT IS TOO LONG*/
/* .wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 7px;
} */

.title {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

Is there any way to assign commented styles if text is too long using only css?
And is there any other way to move span in new line if it is too long? 
Codepen: https://codepen.io/domanskyi/pen/MWYMKqv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding the following to your css: `.text{ display: inline-block; }`

Answer (score 0):

use flex wrap:

```css
.block {
  max-width: 300px;
  background: orange;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.title {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <span class="title">Title:</span>
  <span class="text"> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. </span>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<div class="block">
  <span class="title">Title:</span>
  <span class="text"> Lorem ipsum</span>
</div>
```